# how to store the progress of progressView into arraylist as one element?

Tags: swift, xcode, arraylist, uiprogressview

I want to store the progress of progressView into arraylist as one element

I decleared the array like this

```
var prog = [Float]()
```

and i'm getting the progress like this

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    
    if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
        progressVi = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        print(progressVi)

    }
}
```

I tried this to store it

```
prog.insert(progressVi, at: 0)
```

but I'm getting it like this

```
[0.0071399305, 0.004518387, 0.002777841, 0.0012658517, 0.00086148235, 0.00063292583, 0.000580182, 0.0005274382, 0.0001557393]
```

and it's keep adding ...

So how can I store it as one element?

Comment: Just access element you want to assign the value to by subscription syntax `prog[0] = progressVi`

Comment: @TheDreamsWind .. Fatal error: Index out of range:

Answer (score 1):

You are going to the wrong direction. What you need is to get the dataTask [progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/2908821-progress) object and use it to set your [UIProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview) [observedProgress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview/1619840-observedprogress) property.

> ```
> var observedProgress: Progress? { get set }
> ```
>
> When this property is set, the progress view updates its progress value automatically using information it receives from the [Progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress) object. (Progress updates are animated.) Set the property to nil when you want to update the progress manually. The default value of this property is nil.
> For more information about configuring a progress object to manage progress information, see [Progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress).

Answer (score 0):

### Store single element

To store it as single element of the array simply:

```
var prog = [Float]()
prog = [progresVi]
```

If you insert the item at `0`, the array will grow up every time you insert an element.

### Store multiple elements

In order to store multiple progresses it is necessary to create a model to store the queue.

```
struct Element { 
    let id: UUID
    var progress: Float
}

var stack = [Element]()
```

It is necessary to store the ID for every item you are registering the progress. If you have the ID, then you can update the item progress:

```
let idForItem = UUID()

func getProgress() -> Float { ... }

let newProgress = getProgress()

// Update the stack of elements
if let elementIndice = stack.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == idForItem}) { 
     stack[elementIndice].progress = newProgress
}
```

Comment: well,  it's work fine . but when I download another file . the second progress is add over the first ... but not as a second element

Comment: If you want to store multiple items you need to model that, let me code it as an edition...